# Apache2 bad matching virtualhost

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I have a little problem with virtualhosts.

My configuration is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.site2.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domains/site2.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domains/site1.com
        ServerName www.site1.com

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/....
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/...
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/...
</VirtualHost>
```

If you enter the following URLs into browser:

https://www.site1.com - OK (matches VHost with /var/www/domains/site1.com DocumentRoot)

http://www.site2.com - OK (matches Vhost with /var/www/domains/site2.com DocumentRoot)

but when I try site2.com with https protocol (https://www.site2.com). Apache finds wrong Vhost with /var/www/domains/site1.com DocumentRoot..

Why?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you only have HTTPS configured for site1 and not site2.

You'll need to duplicate the site1 VirtualHost configuration and apply site2's information to it so it'll look something like the one below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domains/site2.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.site2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domains/site2.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/....
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/...
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.site1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domains/site1.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/....
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/...
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/...
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm assuming you have a separate SSL certificate for your other site or are just testing.

You may also run into the issue of hosting multiple domains with HTTPS with only one IP address on your server, in which you should follow the instructions here: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

Answer (score 0):

This is simply how virtual hosts work in Apache. The match for the IP:PORT combination at the TCP layer is checked first. If there are multiple virtual hosts with the "best match", then hostnames (from the HTTP Host: header) are checked.

In your simple case, that means the best match for a request on port 443 is the single *:443 vhost. It will never look at worse matches to find a matching hostname.